# Development and version control workflow in a remote site with several servers

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, version-control, remote-access

I have a website in AWS which consists of four severs: web (front-end), files, database and apps (back-end). This structure is duplicated for production and testing/development. Additionally, I have a local copy of web and apps. I have been working alone developing on the local files and testing changes on the testing servers. I used Bazaar as version control locally.

Now, new developers are coming to the web (front end) part of the project and I have doubts about the correct version control workflow. I know that we will use Git and that local testing is very limited. Also, I would want to restrict the folders they we will be able to read and modify.

What are the best practices with this architecture? What is the best workflow?

Comment: How many extra people are joining the project? Are they only working on from front end, or will they be working on the other parts as well?

Comment: Two new developers. Only front end.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many things. First of all, usually a best practice solution is an overkill for a project ( or at least a team) size like yours.

If you have a long project with a big team, proper automated tests, I would suggest you to have a Jenkis server ( or any other CI tool), where you can run automated tests on every checked in code. You can get detailed reports on test failures, code coverage, etc. You will be able to do automated deployment even to a live environment.

To set up all of this is quite an overhead for the project.
What I'm doing now in a project with a few developers, that we are using VisualStudio Online. This gives us a TFS version controlling. (If you using Git, that's fine too.)

We are having 3 Beanstalk environments (dev,test,prod). (We may have multiple dev environments for different dev teams.) Each deployment is manual, but Elastic Beanstalk has support of one click deployment for several programming languages.

You mentioned, you have a 3( 4) tier web application, that's fine, you are able to set this up in Beanstalk. (Frontend-Worker-RDS + you can set up the file-system manually, depending on your needs.)

So what I suggest is try to use Beanstalk, because it's really easy to use/deploy, especially if you don't have a too unique setup.

Decide if you want to invest to CI/CD tools. (If yes, Jenkins, VisualStudioOnline are great tools.)